# CSS grid property: Creating responsive full-screen "portrait" image grid, retaining the images aspect ratio from screen width of 767 and up

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I wist to make a layout like this one:

[image: Layout URL]

Layout Description:

1. A grid surrounded with a 30px gap
2. Each cell contains an image (430 X 882)

I want the user who enters the page will see only the grid and it's padding (i.e the Viewport area) from screen width of 767px and up, while keeping the 30px gap and the images aspect ratio (even in weird ratios where the width is way longer then the height).

I am not a web developer, but the behavior I seek is like WPF ViewBox which all it does is "scale to fit the content".

Here's what I did:

```
   .grid-container {
        margin: 30px 0;
    }

    .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        grid-gap: 30px 30px;
        grid-template-areas: "a1 a2 a3 a4";
    }    

    .background-cover {
       object-fit: cover;
       width: 100%;
    }


   <div class="grid-container">
   <div class="grid">
      <div class="grayscale grid-cell ">
         <img class="background-cover" src="http://via.placeholder.com/430x882">
      </div>
      <div class="grayscale grid-cell ">
         <img class="background-cover" src="http://via.placeholder.com/430x882">
      </div>
      <div class="grayscale grid-cell ">
         <img class="background-cover" src="http://via.placeholder.com/430x882">
      </div>
      <div class="grayscale grid-cell ">
         <img class="background-cover" src="http://via.placeholder.com/430x882">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what to do to keep the the grid in fullscreen.
I tried setting 90vh height to the grid, but it didn't help.

Am I on the right track? or I should use something else like flex, or even use JS?